# Translating MySQL query into Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, database-schema

I have a web application which currently uses PHP to sort some data stored in a MySQL database.  I am currently enhancing the application by using the Laravel framework but am having trouble equating all the various MySQL commands to those used by `DB` in Laravel.

I have a table which has some duplicate `author` names and want to sum the `citations` column values for those duplicates.  So for example I might have two authors in the table called `John Doe`, one with `30` citations and the other with `20`.  After running the current query I would then have two rows for `John Doe`, both with `50` citations.  I then use `GROUP BY` to get only one instance of the author.  Here is the current query from my PHP code:

```
// sum citations for duplicate authors
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE searchresponse AS r JOIN(SELECT author, SUM(citations) AS citations, COUNT(author) AS n FROM searchresponse GROUP BY author) AS grp ON grp.author = r.author SET r.citations = grp.citations");
```

Now I have been trying something along the lines of the following but I'm not sure how to replicate commands like `AS` or `SET` in Laravel:

```
// select relevant data
$sumData = DB::table('searchresponse')
    -> (something);
// insert selected data into table
foreach ($sumData as $value) {
    DB::table('searchresponse')->insert(
        [
            'author'   => $value->author,
            'citations => $value->citations
        ]
    );
}
```

Basically I need to know how in Laravel you reference a table `AS` something so I can compare it to itself, like in my original method where it referenced `searchresponse AS r`.  Or, in fact, just how to replicate my original PHP MySQL query in Laravel.

**EDIT**

Working on it, this seems more like the kind of thing I need to do:

```
// sum citations for duplicate authors
function sumCites($data) {
    $sumAll = DB::table('searchresponse')
        ->join('searchresponse', 'searchresponse.citations', '=', 'searchresponse.citations')
        ->where('searchresponse.author', '=', 'searchresponse.author')
        ->get();
}
```

But I still get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way to get data:

```
function sumCites($data){
     // Update first
     \DB::update('UPDATE searchresponse AS r 
     JOIN(
        SELECT author, SUM(citations) AS citations, COUNT(author) AS n FROM    searchresponse GROUP BY author
       ) grp 
       ON grp.author = r.author 
       SET r.citations = grp.citations');

     //Now fetch all data from that table
     $sumAll = \DB::table('searchresponse')->get();
     return $sumAll;
}
```

If you want to update the table, you may use your sql directly like

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work unfortunately.  The data in the tables stays the same after running the function.

Comment: Do I not need an `update` in there somewhere to update the data in the table or should the `join` take care of that?

Comment: Please try one more time. I updated the function. Let me know if you get any error.

Comment: Thanks, away from my computer at the moment but will give this a try tomorrow.  One quick question: what does the \ denote before `DB`?

Answer (score 1):

You are joining to the same table, so you need to do the join using table alias, try something like below:

```
// sum citations for duplicate authors
function sumCites($data) {
    $sumAll = DB::update('searchresponse')
        ->join('searchresponse as b', 'searchresponse.citations', '=', 'b.citations')
        ->where('searchresponse.author', '=', 'b.author')
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work for some reason.  Data in the tables doesn't change...

Comment: Do I not need an `update` somewhere in there to update the data in the table?

Comment: The original query seems to select data, if you do update, you have to update certain columns. Let me know what you want to do, I'll update the query.